# what is the meaning of ""I should think not"" in this sentences---- "‘He didn’t give the waiter a tip.’ ‘I should think not, after such bad service"

Tags: sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of ""***I should think not***"" in this sentences---- "‘He didn’t give the waiter a tip.’ ‘I should think not, after such bad service"

Comment: This is the same as your previous question. The meaning is the same as in the phrases you asked about there, i.e. *of course he didn't, why would he?!* There is a sense of *well obviously not!* with *I should think not!* that is not there in *I would think not*, so I don't agree completely with the answer you got in that thread. I think what you might be missing is that the *not* just reprises the not in *he did not give the waiter a tip* - it does not negate *should think*. With an affirmative we would use *I should think so* (*she divorced him immediately* / *I should think so!*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of ‘I should think not!’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/492399/meaning-of-i-should-think-not)

Comment: thank u minty , thank u very much,, you explain very well, you have solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

It would basically mean, 'well, why would he have even considered giving  the waiter a tip if the service was so bad?' or 'of course not'.