# A: Nobody will oppose it. B: I should think not!

Tags: negation

> A: Nobody will oppose it.
>
> B: I should think not!

What's the meaning of 'I should think not!'?

B thinks someone will oppose or not oppose?

Answer (score 2):

It would be understood in context, but usually "I should think not" means "I think people should do it and won't do it." It expresses the expectations of someone (usually someone in a position of authority)

You would use it more often when somebody says, for example

> Pupil: I promise I won't graffiti the school desks.
>
> Teacher: I should think not!

In your example, B means "I'm surprised that you even consider the possibility that someone might oppose it.  I would be very disappointed if any one did" etc.

Comment: What is B's view point? B thinks there is someone opposing it or there is no one opposing it? If B agrees with A, then B should have said "I should think so!"? In this case, 'should think not!' means B thinks someone will oppose it?

Comment: Typically, *I should think not!* has the sense of “I’d be quite surprised (and maybe disappointed or even offended) if it turned out so,” and sometimes blending into “I’m surprised you even suggest the possibility.”

Comment: But also, check [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203762/what-is-the-meaning-of-i-should-think-not-in-this-sentences-he-didn-t) about the same phrase in a somewhat different context.